# How to execute a C program in VS Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

Okay, I am an idiot and I cannot figure out how to compile and run C program in VS Code. How should I do it? I typed in the code itself, so what is next in order for me to see the output in terminal? Thanks for accepting my stupid

Comment: What compiler are u using?

Comment: I am in Visual Studio Code and i dont have any more programs. I used to do stuff in Python and that just worked. If I should get some extra software, please do let me know.

Comment: First of all you need to learn the C development life-cycle: Edit source files; Compile source files to object files; Link object files with libraries to create the executable program; And execute the generated program.

Comment: You need to install a compiler if you haven't already, gcc or clang or MSVC etc.

Comment: It is an editor, not an IDE. Try compiling the source files from your terminal.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=guM4XS43m4I

Comment: Try entering `clang -v` or `gcc -v` in the terminal.

Comment: okay, so i successfully installed MinGW. But when I run the program it outputs "No include path in which to find stdio.h", what could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

link your compiler to vs code. if you are using c, it should be gcc or some other fork. to use the compiler just open the terminal, go to gcc or what your compiler name is, and then run it in terminal(if you right click on code)